# How to read env property file in the config map

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

I have a property file in chart/properties folder. For example **chart/properties/dev** is the file
and the contents of it looks like the below

```
var1=somevalue1
var2=somevalue2


var3=somepwd=

var4=http://someurl.company.com
```

some of the value strings in property file have an =. There are also some empty lines in the property file.

and **chart/configmap.yaml** looks like below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: env-configmap
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
data:
{{ range .Files.Lines "properties"/.Values.env.required.environment }}
  {{ . | replace "=" ": " }}
{{ end }}
```

**Generated yaml file:**

```
---
# Source: app/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: env-configmap
  namespace: default
data:

  var1: somevalue1

  var2: somevalue2
  
  var3: somepwd:

  var4: http://someurl.company.com
```

The generated output property entries are missing double quote in the value, as a result deployment complains of it when the value strings contain special characters.

I'm expecting the configmap.yaml data block to be a proper yaml (Indent 2) like file with the above changes. With above changes, there are extra lines after each property entry in yaml file. I got this to work partially when there are no blank lines and no value strings with =. Need help to get this working correctly.

**Expected yaml file:**

```
---
# Source: app/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: env-configmap
  namespace: default
data:
  var1: "somevalue1"
  var2: "somevalue2"
  var3: "somepwd="
  var4: "http://someurl.company.com"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow go template syntax to do that. I update config.yaml like following works

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: env-configmap
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
data:
  {{ range .Files.Lines "properties"/.Values.env.required.environment }}
    {{- if ne . "" -}}
    {{- $parts := splitn "=" 2 . -}} # details about split function http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/string_slice.html
    {{ $parts._0 }}: {{ $parts._1 | quote }}
    {{end}}
  {{ end }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not comment on your question because of my reputation. If it is possible for your case, you can use the config map as a file. I think Reading the property file in your code is easier.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#using-configmaps-as-files-from-a-pod

Comment: Due to some reasons,  i can't do that. I have to use the templating language and feed the env. I'm more looking for an anwer around that.